# Can't compile Xamarin project, four errors when I compile

Tags: xamarin.android

This is a mobile app written in Xamarin. Latest version of Xamarin. Won't compile the android project.  iOS compiles fine.  Installed latest 'everything'.  Tried deleting obj/bin, packages and restoring.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(154,3): error APT2062: failed linking references.

/Users/userX/code/work/example-app/Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid/obj/Debug/lp/1/jl/res/values/values.xml(0,0): Error APT2260: style attribute 'attr/cardBackgroundColor (aka Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid:attr/cardBackgroundColor)' not found. (APT2260)

/Users/userX/code/work/example-app/Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid/obj/Debug/lp/1/jl/res/values/values.xml(0,0): Error APT2260: style attribute 'attr/cardElevation (aka Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid:attr/cardElevation)' not found. (APT2260) (Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(3,3): Error APT2260: resource style/CardView (aka Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid:style/CardView) not found. (APT2260) (Example.Services.Client.Forms.Droid)

Comment: Try turning off aapt2 and see if it builds. that isn't a fix, but it will at lease let you know it's aapt2 related.

Comment: @Steve According to your error message, please check the 'Styles.xml' format is properly or not, I search one thread at github, you can take a look:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3822